# Let users and reviewers know when a moderator clears flags on a post

Tags: feature-request, flags, declined-flags

I've dismissed a number of flags that have been generated by our awesome-but-occasionally-over-sensitive review team. The most common issues like this are on link-only answers. While these generate flags faster than a troop of kids learning semaphore, I'm reluctant to delete them when they're still the best available answer. I'm simply following the "what's best for the internet" rule.

That might be a flaw in my moderating but I'd like to think I'm fair about it. My problem is that once I've cleared the flag(s) the post still attract reviews and that means more people spending time on something without any idea that a moderator has staked a position and that can often result in something returning to the mod queue.

Regardless of the second (or third) decision, this flag-tennis match is a waste of time. When we have as many flags as we have, we're really like to save as much time as possible. What's most frustrating, this is all stuff that could be quite easily tweaked to be a non-issue. Here are a few ideas:

- Stop other people reviewing something when a mod reviews it. There might be some communities where the moderators are too green for this but on Ask Ubuntu the moderators are seasoned veteran reviewers. When we've reviewed something in the mod queue, it should be removed from the other queues.
- If that's too dirty, how about just making reviewers aware? A notice above the post during review: "Oli ♦ cleared flags on this post, 19 hours ago". This is similar to how mods see what other mods do in the flag queue.
- Let people looking at the post directly know (like an asterisk and tooltip on the flag link) and if they click flag, let them know again by spelling it out in the flag dialogue.
- Add decline reasons that aren't counted against the flaggers. Even if the flag is technically correct, there are occasions where I'd like to decline it in a way that leaves a mark without prejudice. So being able to decline a flag and it score +1 or even 0 on the user's helpful flag count but still being able to pass a message back.
- And by extension, advertise previous decline reasons on a post during review or on its flag screen.

This does expose all users to more data but if you're going to let people review, you've got to let people learn the process and understand why some things aren't automatically being nuked from orbit.

Comment: Also, this would be nice to see on the 10k flag review screen. (Is this what you meant in #2?)

Comment: @AaronBrager I had meant in `/review/` but I agree that the 10k queue is a good place too.

Comment: If you're dismissing *that many* flags on individual posts that this is a real problem, this suggests that the site you're moderating on has an issue with the users not understanding how the site works or your actions as a moderator not being aligned with how the community at large thinks the site should work. It might be worth fixing those expectations as a longer term way of reducing the flags.

Comment: @RobM That's certainly part of the solution but even if the reviews on a post carry on (after a mod has said it's okay) and gets "No action needed", there's still wasted time. SE's strength is in the pile of humans that work it but that doesn't mean the pile has the collective time (or patience) to keep redoing things. It's a duplication of effort that can be streamlined.